# In grammar, what type of word would this made-up word "Tshi" be?

Tags: grammar

From Red Letter Media's insightful review of Revenge of the Sith:

"Tshi [meaning] disappointed in the cooking of the duck meat."

Presumably the context is that it is a feeling one might have. As in "The guests were Tshi after dinner".

If it were a real word for this, what kind of word would it be (noun/adjective/verb etc)? I would guess adjective like "disappointed", but could it be an adverb since it affects the verb of cooking?

What I am asking is, if this was an actual translation definition in an English - Gibberish dictionary, what would the word type be, e.g. noun, adjective, verb, etc.

Comment: I disagree with the closure of the question. It's pretty self explanatory what the question is. If any of the closers needed clarification, they should have asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking "what if this word was adopted to English" because otherwise we can't really answer you without understanding the rules of the language it came from- which sounds fictional?

There are many similar words that English adopted because there wasn't a direct translation: [schadenfreude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schadenfreude) comes to mind.

But the answer is **it depends how the word is used.**

- If we would say "I am **tshi**" then that **might** be an adjective. This is similar to how we might use "I am dissapointed."
- If we would say "I ate **tshi**" then that **might** be an adverb. This is similar to how we might use "I ate dissapointedly."
- If we would say "**Tshi** was felt at dinner" then that might be a noun. This is similar to how we might use "Dissapointment was felt at dinner."

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question with an assumption of how the word would be used in a sentence.

Comment: @AndFisher Your example sentence uses the word as a noun.

Comment: Ah, I believe my assumption was wrong, since the definition is "disappointed" rather than "disappointment"

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and sorry it wad such a nonsense question ;)

Comment: @AndFisher I don't think it was a nonsense question, I just don't think it has a very satisfying answer, since it's going to depend on how the word is used. Even English words can have different senses depending on how they're used. You can't tell what a word is without seeing how it's used in a sentence, and even then, it might have a different sense in a different sentence.